# XML XSD schema validation failing with error 'The 'http://www.xchanging.com/USM/xml:MyCode' element is not declared.'

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I have a xml which need to be validated with the schema. Both are present below . 
I have two schemas defined.

XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<Jv-Ins-Reinsurance  
xmlns="http://www.ACORD.org/standards/Jv-Ins-Reinsurance/2008-1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:lm="http://www.xchanging.com/USM/xml" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ACORD.org/standards/Jv-Ins-Reinsurance/2008-1 Jv-Ins-Reinsurance-2008-1.xsd"> 
<TechAccount> 
<Extension> 
<lm:MyCode>Test</lm:MyCode> 
</Extension> 
</TechAccount>
</Jv-Ins-Reinsurance>
```

Schema to Test with :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:usm="http://www.xchanging.com/USM/xml" xmlns="http://www.ACORD.org/standards/Jv-Ins-Reinsurance/2008-1" targetNamespace="http://www.ACORD.org/standards/Jv-Ins-Reinsurance/2008-1" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="2008-1b">
<xs:import namespace="http://www.xchanging.com/USM/xml" schemaLocation="USM.xsd"/>

  <xs:element name="Jv-Ins-Reinsurance" type="Jv-Ins-ReinsuranceType"/>
  <xs:element name="TechAccount" type="TechAccountType"/>

  <xs:complexType name="Jv-Ins-ReinsuranceType">
    <xs:choice>
      <xs:element ref="TechAccount"/>
    </xs:choice>
   </xs:complexType>

     <xs:complexType name="TechAccountType">
    <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="Extension" type="TechAccount_ExtensionType" 
          minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="TechAccount_ExtensionType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref = "usm:MyCode" />
     </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

The imported schema is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://www.xchanging.com/USM/xml" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.xchanging.com/USM/xml" elementFormDefault="unqualified">
 <xs:element name="MyCode" type="xs:string" />
</xs:schema>
```

I am ending up with error : 
The 'http://www.xchanging.com/USM/xml:MyCode' element is not declared.

I have tried multiple things on this but this is not getting resolved. Even the example on the link : http://www.xfront.com/ZeroOneOrManyNamespaces.html is also performing the same.

Comment: Your example validates fine with me (using Xerces, xmllint, and Saxon-EE). Please describe your validation setting.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the all the XML's  and XSD working fine in NotePad++  . 
I wrote c# application and that was not working, later on I found that the C# logic is not adding the schema 'http://www.xchanging.com/USM/xml' and that's why not able to find the element in another schema which is done internally by tools like notepad++. 
Thanks, Fabian https://stackoverflow.com/users/2898506/fabian for looking into it.

Here is the thing I was missing (in the first few lines adding the schema)

```
 schemas.Add(null, XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(schema2)));

   schemas.Add(null, XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(schema3)));

   string message = string.Empty;

   doc = new XDocument(xml);

            doc.Validate(schemas, (o, e) =>
            {
                message = e.Message;
                isValidated = false;
            });
```

Got to know that we need to add all the imported schemas before we call validate so validator gets knowledge of everything . My Bad :/